# How to merge Array of Objects based on the same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of Objects:

```
var array = [{
    country: "Austria",
    name: "2019-01-04T23:00:00.000Z",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    country: "Austria",
    name: "2019-01-11T23:00:00.000Z",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    country: "Austria",
    name: "2019-01-18T23:00:00.000Z",
    value: "1"
  }
]
```

I want manipulate this to achieve this result:

```
var array = [{
  country: "Austria",
  series: [{
      name: "2019-01-04T23:00:00.000Z",
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      name: "2019-01-11T23:00:00.000Z",
      value: "3"
    },
    {
      name: "2019-01-18T23:00:00.000Z",
      value: "1"
    }
  ]
}]
```

I read many questions but none helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop thorugh the array. Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get `country` and `rest` of the properties separately. Add each unique `country` to `group` object as key and push the `rest` object to the `series` array. Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values as an array

```js
const array=[{country:"Austria",name:"2019-01-04T23:00:00.000Z",value:"1"},{country:"Austria",name:"2019-01-11T23:00:00.000Z",value:"3"},{country:"Austria",name:"2019-01-18T23:00:00.000Z",value:"1"}];

const group = {};

array.forEach(({ country, ...rest }) => {
  group[country] = group[country] || { country, series: [] };
  group[country].series.push(rest)
})

console.log(Object.values(group))
```

Comment: It works. I decide to vote on this answer because I think it's a compact form that makes it easy to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
var map = {};

for(var entity of array) {
    if(!map[entity.country]) {
        map[entity.country] = {
            country: entity.country,
            series: [
                {
                    name: entity.name,
                    value: entity.value
                }
            ]
        };
    }
    else {
        map[entity.country].series.push({
            name: entity.name,
            value: entity.value            
        });
    }
}

var mappedArray = Object.values(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is functional solution without for loops and mutable variables:

```
const result = array.reduce((carry, item) => {
    if (!carry.includes(item.country)) {
        carry.push(item.country);
    }
    return carry;
}, []).map(country => {
    return {
        country: country,
        series: array.filter(item => item.country === country).map(item => {
            return {
                name: item.name,
                value: item.value
            };
        })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
const result = array
    .map(
        c => ({
            country: c.country,
            series: array
                .filter(d => d.country === c.country)
                .map(
                    d => ({
                        name: d.name,
                        value: d.value
                    })
                )
        })
    )
```